# Inserting uniques into link table on update

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a scenario where I'm updating a blog post which has multiple tags assigned to it via a many to many relationship (in a link table called `blog_link_tags`) as below:

```
...

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$blogPost = $em->getRepository('MyBlogBundle:Blog')->find($postId);


$blogPost
    ->setTitle( $request->request->get('post_title', '') )
    ->setBody( $request->request->get('post_body', '') )
    ->setLive(true);


$postTags = json_decode( $request->request->get('post_tags', '') );
$tagRepository = $em->getRepository('MyBlogBundle:BlogTag');

foreach($postTags as $postTag) {
    $tag = $tagRepository->find( $postTag->id );
    if (!$tag) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Tag not found: ' . $tag->title);
    }
    $blogPost->addTag($tag);
}

$em->flush();

....
```

As you can probably tell though, if I edit a blog post and add a new tag then it will create duplicates records.

What is the best way to either truncate the `blog_link_tag` table of records of the current blog post id, OR only insert those tag ids that are unique? Would it be to do it on the following line within the foreach loop:

```
$tag = $tagRepository->find( $postTag->id );
```

But instead check to see if the tag existed AND if it was not yet present in the link table? Or does Doctrine 2 offer a better way to achieve such an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned I would first create a **FormType** for the Post entity so that I don't have to write any **messy** code into the controller and everything is automated, clean and secure.

Next, I would manage the tags within the Post entity as in:

```
class Post
{

    private $tags;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setTags($tags)
    {
        $this->tags->clear();

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $this->addTag($tag);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addTag(Tag $tag)
    {
         if (!$this->tags->contains($tag)) {
             $this->tags[] = $tag;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did the job perfectly. I like the idea of managing the duplicates within the post entity to reduce controller size. I'm relatively new to Symfony so I will look into creating a FormType as it sounds like the best way to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 solutions for that assuming `$blogPost` is the owning side :

First solution, use `$blogPost->getTags()->clear()` before the `foreach`. Careful with this one, it will remove all the linked tags in the `blog_link_tags`. But it is fine if you add them again in your foreach. Depends of the content `$postTags`

The second one is to test `if(!$blogPost->getTags()->contains($tag))` before `$blogPost->addTag($tag);`

Remember that you are dealing with [ArrayCollection](http://api.nellafw.org/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) in a `many-to-many` relation

**NB :**
I think you have a typo here :

```
 if (!$tag) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Tag not found: ' . $tag->title);
    }
```

If `$tag` doesn't exit, you can't use `$tag->title`. I think you wanted to use `$postTag->title`